# Unable to rename using the os module in python

Tags: python

```
import os

if not os.path.exists("data"):
    os.mkdir("data")

base_directory = "E:/OS Module/data"

for i in range(0, 100):
    folder_name = f"Day{i}"
    folder_path = os.path.join(base_directory, folder_name)
    os.makedirs(folder_path, exist_ok=True)
    python_file_path = os.path.join(folder_path, "script.py")
    text_file_path = os.path.join(folder_path, "hello.txt")
    with open(python_file_path, "w") as f:
        f.write("# This is a sample file\n")  # Used to write inside the file
        f.write(f"print(\"Hii I am Iron Man from {folder_name}\")\n")

    with open(text_file_path, "w") as a:
        a.write("This is a text file.")

    print(f"Created Folder: {folder_name}")

print("Folders and files made")

for i in range(0, 100):
    folder_name = f"Day{i}"
    folder_path = os.path.join(base_directory, folder_name)
    new_folder_name = f"Tutorial {i}"
    new_folder_path = os.path.join(base_directory, new_folder_name)
    os.makedirs(folder_path, exist_ok=True)
    os.rename(folder_path, new_folder_path)
    print(f"Renamed folders: {new_folder_name}")
```

Even thougn I'm using 'exist_ok = True', I am getting this error while trying to rename the folders -

FileExistsError: [WinError 183] Cannot create a file when that file already exists

I also looked for solutions regarding this error but couldn't find anything.
It would be great if someone could explain why this is happening.

Thank you

Comment: side note: avoid spaces in file(type file and folder) name. It's always a source of problem.

Comment: You never check if `new_folder_path` exists in the file system.

Comment: @Matthias I tried that by using if statement. Same error

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First of all hardcode the base directory path only when you want to store it to an absolute place in your system otherwise just keep it a relative path to the directory you are in.

Edit:
Try replacing the way to rename folders. This should fix the error.

Edit2:
The error is causing in this piece of code because what you are trying to do is first create a folder then rename it.
On a clean build, it works but when it's not a clean build it doesn't work because the Tutorial 0, folder already exists and you are trying to rename it to the name of a folder that already exists. You can't create 2 folders by the same name.

here's the code

```
import shutil, os

if not os.path.exists("data"):
    os.mkdir("data")

base_directory = "data"
# base_directory = "E:/OS Module/data"

for i in range(0, 100):
    folder_name = f"Day{i}"
    folder_path = os.path.join(base_directory, folder_name)

    os.makedirs(folder_path, exist_ok=True)

    python_file_path = os.path.join(folder_path, "script.py")
    text_file_path = os.path.join(folder_path, "hello.txt")

    with open(python_file_path, "w") as f:
        f.write("# This is a sample file\n")  # Used to write inside the file
        f.write(f"print(\"Hii I am Iron Man from {folder_name}\")\n")

    with open(text_file_path, "w") as a:
        a.write("This is a text file.")

    print(f"Created Folder: {folder_name}")

print("Folders and files made")


"""
The error is causing in this piece of code because what you are trying to do is first create a folder then rename it.
On a clean build, it works but when it's not a clean build it doesn't work because the Tutorial 0, folder already exists and you are trying to rename it to the name of a folder that already exists. You can't create 2 folders by the same name.

for i in range(0, 100):
    folder_name = f"Day{i}"
    folder_path = os.path.join(base_directory, folder_name)

    new_folder_name = f"Tutorial {i}"
    new_folder_path = os.path.join(base_directory, new_folder_name)

    os.makedirs(folder_path, exist_ok=True)
    os.rename(folder_path, new_folder_path)

    print(f"Renamed folders: {new_folder_name}")
"""

for i in range(0, 100):
    folder_name = f"Day{i}"
    folder_path = os.path.join(base_directory, folder_name)

    new_folder_name = f"Tutorial {i}"
    new_folder_path = os.path.join(base_directory, new_folder_name)

    if os.path.exists(new_folder_path):
        shutil.rmtree(new_folder_path)

    os.makedirs(folder_path, exist_ok=True)
    os.rename(folder_path, new_folder_path)

    print(f"Renamed folders: {new_folder_name}")
```

Hope it helped :)

Comment: FileExistsError: [WinError 183] Cannot create a file when that file already exists: 'data\\Day0' -> 'data\\Tutorial 0'
I changed the path but still it shows the same error

Comment: Have you tried doing a clean build? First delete all the files and folders that your program generates programmatically. Then rerun your program.

If still the issue is there then may you please provide the folder structure and the full path of your project?

Edit: I'm not getting any errors from this code by the way

Comment: It worked after doing a clean build, thank you so much! But I still don't understand why it didn't before. I mean when working on a big project, we might need to rename folders like this and we can't just delete the folders. What should we do then?

Comment: I edited the code, that fixed the error.

Comment: Hey, I just updated the code ensuring a permanent fix. You should consider checking it

Comment: Hello, I didn't understand what you mean to say in Edit2, can you please elaborate?

Comment: "Edit" means the first edit I made to this post, and "Edit2" means I'm again editing my post but keeping the previous edit as well. The original edit might have lost it's relevance due to new edit being made but I decided to keep it.

Also if this post helped you solve your problem please consider upvoting it and marking it as accepted. It would help me a lot.

Comment: That I understand. I am asking about this:
"The error is causing in this piece of code because what you are trying to do is first create a folder then rename it. On a clean build, it works but when it's not a clean build it doesn't work because the Tutorial 0, folder already exists and you are trying to rename it to the name of a folder that already exists. You can't create 2 folders by the same name." I mean when I am running the code, there is no folder by the name which I am going to rename. Then how can the folder already exist?

Comment: Oh sorry for misunderstanding.

Your program was initially trying rename a folder to an already existing folder.

In a clean build there are no folders named `Day0` and `Tutorial 0`. So when you ran your program it worked as intended. However when you ran your progarm again, it did created `Day0` but when it tried to rename `Tutorial 0` it threw an error which actually meant `Cannot rename a folder to a folder that already exists.`, and by deleting `Tutorial 0` programmatically before renaming we solve this issue permanently.

Hope you understood :)

Comment: At the stage where I am trying to rename the folders from Day{i} to Tutorial {i}, there are no folders by the name Tutorial {i}

Comment: In a clean build there is no folders by the name Tutorial {i}, but when you rerun the program without a clean build, the Tutorial {i} folders still exist in the data folder. These already existing folders cause `os.rename` to throw error as you are trying to rename Day{i} to Tutorial {i} which already exists in the second run. By deleting them beforehand, you fix this issue

Answer (score 0):

See if this works

```py
for i in range(0, 100):
    folder_name = f"Day{i}"
    folder_path = os.path.join(base_directory, folder_name)
    new_folder_name = f"Tutorial {i}"
    new_folder_path = os.path.join(base_directory, new_folder_name)
    
    # Check if the source folder exists before renaming
    if os.path.exists(folder_path):
        os.rename(folder_path, new_folder_path)
        print(f"Renamed folders: {new_folder_name}")
    else:
        print(f"Source folder does not exist: {folder_path}")
```

Comment: What did you change ? Why do you think it would solve the issue ?

Comment: Still getting the same error